Wikipedia's definition of constant sheaf
This seems to be the definition of a constant sheaf on wikipedia.

The constant sheaf on a topological space $X$ associated to a set $A$ is a sheaf of sets on $X$ whose stalks are all equal to $A$.

I saw this question, but I'm still very confused about how it is equivalent to other definitions. First, the stalks are colimits of things at different points. How can we expect them to be "equal" or canonically isomorphic to each other? If we consider the sheaf of locally constant functions, then its stalks are not equal, only canonically isomorphic. Is "the stalks are all isomorphic" sufficient?
Even if they are equal, I can't show that there is a section with germ $a$ at every point, for $a\in A$. Why is that true?
Question: Is this definition (which seems to only involve stalks) sufficient to characterize the constant sheaf up to isomorphism? If so, why? If not, what is a counterexample?

There is a construction of a sheaf with all stalks isomorphic to a specified set. A constant sheaf is any sheaf isomorphic to such a sheaf. But this is much too tedious to write out in full.

@ZhenLin You mean it's just wikipedia's phrasing is inacurate?

This sentence is not the actual definition, which is given later in the same paragraph.
The property given is not precisely formulated and does not characterize the constant sheaf up to isomorphism. Any locally constant sheaf on a connected space $X$ has every stalk isomorphic to the same set $A$, but there are plenty of locally constant sheaves that are not constant (e.g. those arising from non-trivial covering spaces on a nice topological space). To make this difference precise, you have to start discussing monodromy, which measures whether you can consistently identify the stalks with one another.

The first sentence on the page is not the definition. It is a property. In the same paragraph the precise definition is given. Many Wikipedia pages follow this style.

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks, I misunderstood because of the OP.

@MartinBrandenburg Well then maybe they shouldn't use the boldface because it usually implies defining something.... Also both sentences are in the form "The constant sheaf is sth" so the phrasing is really misleading.

Everyone is invited to improve Wikipedia! You can also link this very question in the talk page to justify the editing. Remember that Wikipedia is a community project which evolves (locally) constantly.

But just to give you another typical example how Wikipedia pages start. The page for prime ideals (ring theory) starts with: In algebra, a prime ideal is a subset of a ring that shares many important properties of a prime number in the ring of integers. Clearly this is not a definition. Also the wording "subset" is a bit weird when you think about prime numbers, a priori. The only purpose of this sentence is to give you a rough idea.

Colimits are only unique up to isomorphism. When we say that a colimit is equal to something, we always only mean that this something is a colimit of the given diagram.
In the case of the sheaf $F$ of locally constant functions with values in $A$, the maps $F(U) \to A$, $s \mapsto s(x)$ (where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$) form a colimit cocone, meaning that $A$ is one choice for the colimit $F_x$. For any other given construction of the colimit, it means that the induced homomorphism $F_x \to A$ is an isomorphism.
Equality for objects in category theory always refers to a canonical isomorphism.

But there is no canonical map between stalks at different points a priori.

a priori yes, but there is one, because the stalks all have a canonical isomorphism to $A$
